# QStandardItem + QComboBox

Tags: qt, qcombobox

I am trying to put a `QComboBox` into a `QStandardItem` to be used in a `QStandardItemModel`. I have been looking around and I cannot find an answer, any ideas?

Comment: This answer to one of my questions might help you as wel :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764790/which-model-to-subclass-view-to-use-for-a-list-of-custom-objects/6769603#6769603

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't store a `QComboBox` in a `QStandardItemModel`.  Let's say you have the following choices:

A
B
C
D

and you have a list with two items in a `QListView`, the first value being A the second being D:

```
 QListView* pView = new QListView();
 QStandardItemModel* pModel = new QStandardItemModel();
 pView->setModel(pModel);
 pModel->appendRow(new QStandardItem("A"));
 pModel->appendRow(new QStandardItem("D"));
```

What we created above is a list widget which will display the values of "A" and "D".  Now, to the `QComboBox`.  I assume you want that to edit the values of "A" and "D" in the list.  For this, you need to create a `QItemDelegate`.

See http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qitemdelegate.html

An attempt:

```
 class ComboBoxDelegate : public QItemDelegate
 {
    Q_OBJECT

 public:
    ComboBoxDelegate(QObject *parent = 0);

    QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                       const QModelIndex &index) const;

    void setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model,
                   const QModelIndex &index) const;

    void updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor,
     const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
};

ComboBoxDelegate::ComboBoxDelegate(QObject *parent)
 : QItemDelegate(parent)
{
}

QWidget *ComboBoxDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent,
 const QStyleOptionViewItem &/* option */,
 const QModelIndex &/* index */) const
{
   QComboBox *editor = new QComboBox(parent);
   editor->addItem("A");
   editor->addItem("B");
   editor->addItem("C");
   editor->addItem("D");

   return editor;
}

void ComboBoxDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor,
                                 const QModelIndex &index) const
{
   QString value = index.model()->data(index, Qt::EditRole).toString();

   QComboBox *cBox = static_cast<QComboBox*>(editor);
   cBox->setCurrentIndex(cBox->findText(value));
}

void ComboBoxDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model,
                                const QModelIndex &index) const
{
   QComboBox *cBox = static_cast<QComboBox*>(editor);
   QString value = cBox->currentText();

   model->setData(index, value, Qt::EditRole);
}    

void ComboBoxDelegate::updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor,
 const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &/* index */) const
{
   editor->setGeometry(option.rect);
}
```

And then you need to set the delegate on the `QListView` to make it work, see:

```
pView->setItemDelegate(new ComboBoxDelegate(pView));
```