# Which model to subclass / view to use for a list of custom objects

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, qt, qt4

I don't have enough experience with Qt yet to make a good design choice. Any help by experienced Qt programmers would be very appreciated.
I'm trying to find out which model to subclass, which view to use, what delegate subclassing / extending I should do...

My problem is similar to: I have these zones I would like to display, 1 per row:

```
class Zone{

    //inputs
    string country;  //edited with a QComboBox
    string city;     //edited with a QComboBox
    int ageMin;

    //stored result
    int nbInhabitantsOlderThanMin;
}
```

Here's what I'd like to do, and the design choices each requirements makes me think of:

- I would like to display a **list** of them (--> *QListView* )
- But to display 1 item I need several columns (--> *QTableView* )
- I would like a double click on a row to trigger **editing in a custom widget**, since nbInhabitantsOlderThanMin can not be edited, and choosing a country restricts the list of cities that can be chosen in the QComboBox (and vice versa in my real example) (--> I should probably use a *QDataWidgetMapper* (or subclass?) somewhere...)

  So whereas the edition of a row should  happen in a widget, the display is simple / not custom, and subclassing a delegate (*QStyledItemDelegate* for instance) (I'm not so sure about this one) doesn't seem to be the right way to have 1 custom widget with many child input widget to edit the 3 fields at the same time.
  I think the data to model would favor a model subclassing *QAbstractListModel*, but the display with many columns compatible with default delegate viewing favors a *QAbstractTableModel*..

So I don't really know which design to go for. Any experienced help connecting the dots is very welcome :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QDataWidgetMapper is a slightly different thing.  It is a way to display one item from a Model (ex. QStandardItemModel), using custom controls.  You can read more about it [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq21-datawidgetmapper.html), with accompanying snapshots and an example of how to implement one.

While it is certainly cool, I don't think it is what you want here.  Mostly because you specified that you want to view your items in a list format.  However, you could display all your items in a simple list, double-click which would open a dialog using the QDataWidgetMapper.  In which case all you would need to do with a QListView/QListWidget is implement the double-click event.

Still, I personally don't like the added burden of the extra window on a user.  I prefer to use popups sparingly.  But if you like that approach, then go ahead.  [This](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/sql-drilldown.html) is another example of the QDataWidgetMapper which is pretty nice.

My preferred approach is still to use the QTableView, and provide delegates for the columns that need specialized editing.  [Here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/modelview.html) is a great walk-through of all things Model/View.  So if you decide to use the QListView or QTableView it will give you a great start.  It also talks about how you can create delegates to edit fields however you want.

So, how do you create a custom delegate?  Basically, you just inherit from QItemDelegate.  There are some examples in the link above, but I'll highlight a few salient points.

```
QWidget *ComboBoxDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent,
     const QStyleOptionViewItem &/* option */,
     const QModelIndex &index) const
 {
     QComboBox *editor = new QComboBox (parent);
     //  Add items to the combobox here.
     //  You can use the QModelIndex passed above to access the model
     //  Add find out what country was selected, and therefore what cities
     //  need to be listed in the combobox

     return editor;
 }

void ComboBoxDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor,
                                     const QModelIndex &index) const
 {
     int value = index.model()->data(index, Qt::EditRole).toInt();

     QComboBox  *comboBox= static_cast<QComboBox *>(editor);
     int _SelectedItem = // Figure out which is the currently selected index;
     comboBox->setCurrentIndex(_SelectedItem);
 }

void ComboBoxDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model,
                                    const QModelIndex &index) const
 {
     QComboBox  *comboBox= static_cast<QComboBox *>(editor);
     comboBox->interpretText();
     int value = comboBox->currentIndex();
     //  Translate the current index to whatever you actually want to
     // set in your model.

     model->setData(index, value, Qt::EditRole);
}
```

Fill in the gaps that I left in my example and you have your Delegate.
Now, how to use this in your QTableView:

You can set a delegate for a particular column of your table as follows:

```
setItemDelegateForColumn(_ColumnIndex, new ComboBoxDelegate(_YourTableModel));
```

And, if you want to prevent certain columns from being editable:

```
_YourTableModel->setColumnEditable(_ColumnIndex, false);
```

Once you have your model set up, everything else should take care of itself.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Liz, this has been tremendously helpfull; many thanks to you!

Answer (score 1):

I just finished something very similar to this in that I needed multiple fields for each object which I wanted in a row. The way I did it, which worked out very well, was to subclass QAbstractListmodel and use a custom ListItem. I kind of faked the columns by having a custom delegate and using some javascript to figure out the size of the largest thing in each field, and then set the column size to that width. I think this is the easiest way of doing it.

For the comment below, zone would inherit from:

```
class ListItem: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ListItem(QObject* parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}
    virtual ~ListItem() {}
    virtual QString id() const = 0;
    virtual QVariant data(int role) const = 0;
    virtual QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const = 0;

signals:
    void dataChanged();
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. What exactly do you mean by custom ListItem ? What would the `class Zone` derive from in your model?

Comment: A Item has to implement a couple of things, so I made a class that zone would inherit from. Posted the code in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should subclass `QAbstractItemDelegate` (or `QItemDeleage`, that could be more convenient), where reimplement `createEditor`, `setEditorData` and `setModelData`.

Than, you should set your own itemDelegate (see `QAbstractItemView::setItemDelegate`).

It's commonly no difference, what widget to use to present data: It could be either `QTreeWidet`, or `QTreeView`, or `QTableWidget`, or `QTableView`. Note, that "widgets" are easier to use, than "views", but they are not so powerfull

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you explain a bit further how the multiple columns would be handeled with this design? Also, does your suggestion work with a `QDataWidgetMapper` or do you not recommend it?