# Qt: Create a QItemDelegate to have a custom editor (Combo Boxes) in a QTableView with QStandardItemModel

Tags: qt, qtableview, qitemdelegate, qstandarditemmodel

I need to implement a table in Qt that shows a Combo Box on each row on a particular column.

So far based on this example: 
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/itemviews-spinboxdelegate.html
and on this question:
[QStandardItem + QComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135505/qstandarditem-qcombobox)
I succesfully managed to create a QItemDelegate.

My problem is that everything works fine if I implement it from my main() function in main.cpp, but it does not work well if I insert the table in Qt Designer to use it then within a function of MainWindow class in mainwindow.cpp.

Could you please give me a clue? Thanks in advance!

**Delegation on main.cpp (it works well, when I double click on the second column it shows a Combo Box):**

```
QStandardItemModel model(4, 2);
QTableView tableView;
tableView.setModel(&model);
ComboBoxDelegate delegate;
tableView.setItemDelegateForColumn(1,&delegate);
tableView.horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);

for (int row = 0 ; row < 4; ++row) {
    for (int col = 0; col < 2; ++col) {
        QModelIndex index = model.index(row, col, QModelIndex());
        model.setData(index, QVariant((row+1) * (col+1)));
    }
}
tableView.show();
```

**Delegation on mainwindow.cpp alternative 1 (it shows an empty table)**

```
QStandardItemModel model(4,2);
ui->tablePoint->setModel(&model);
ComboBoxDelegate delegate;
ui->tablePoint->setItemDelegateForColumn(1,&delegate);
ui->tablePoint->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);

for (int row = 0 ; row < 4; ++row) {
    for (int col = 0; col < 2; ++col) {
        QModelIndex index = model.index(row, col, QModelIndex());
        model.setData(index, QVariant((row+1) * (col+1)));
    }
}
```

**Delegation on mainwindow.cpp alternative 2 (it shows the table but when I double click on the second column it does not show the Combo Box. Instead it shows the regular Spin Box):**

```
QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel(4,2);
ui->tablePoint->setModel(model);
ComboBoxDelegate delegate;
ui->tablePoint->setItemDelegateForColumn(1,&delegate);
ui->tablePoint->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);

for (int row = 0 ; row < 4; ++row) {
    for (int col = 0; col < 2; ++col) {
        QModelIndex index = model->index(row, col, QModelIndex());
        model->setData(index, QVariant((row+1) * (col+1)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that in both mainwindow.cpp cases, the code you show is in the constructor, you do the classic "coming from java, python, perl or any language where you don't give a damn about memory management" error to allocate your model and/or delegate on the stack rather than on the heap.

In c++, stuff allocated on the stack (e.g. `QStandardItemModel model(4,2);`) is destroyed when returning from the function, while stuff allocated on the heap (e.g. `QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel(4,2);` lives until you `delete` it).
Case 1 works because stuff allocated on the stack in `main()` lives for the duration of the app.

Bottom line: for case 3, do a `ComboBoxDelegate* delegate = new ComboBoxDelegate();` and `ui->tablePoint->setItemDelegateForColumn(1,delegate);`

Comment: Thank you Koying! You know I realized what was the problem and fix the program. But I wasn't able to answer my own question before 8 hours since I'm less than 100 reputation.
It's not the first time I make this mistake and I believe it won't be the last. You are right, I come from a non object oriented programming world and these kind of things are a pain in the *** for me. Thank you for sharing your knowledge with me. Greetings. Francisco