# Qt, QStandarItemModel: Delegation items on custom QComboBox filling its contents from instantiator of model

Tags: qt, qabstractitemmodel, qvariant, qstandarditemmodel

I need to implement a table in Qt that shows a `QComboBox` on each row on a particular column.

Based on this question: [QStandardItem + QComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135505/qstandarditem-qcombobox) I succesfully managed to create a `QItemDelegate`. In that example the `QComboBox` contents are defined statically on `ComboBoxDelegate` class, but in my case I need to define the `QComboBox` contents within the function where the `QStandardItemModel` is created.

The model is defined inside a `MainWindow` class method:

```
void MainWindow::fooHandler()  {
    QStandardItemModel*  mymodel = new QStandardItemModel;
    ui->tablePoint->setModel(mymodel);
    ComboBoxDelegate* delegate=new ComboBoxDelegate;
    ui->tablePoint->setItemDelegateForColumn(2,delegate);

    QStringList Pets;
    Pets.append("cat");
    Pets.append("dog");
    Pets.append("parrot");

    // So far this is how I tried to store data under `Qt::UserRole` in "mymodel":

    QModelIndex idx = mymodel->index(0, 2, QModelIndex());
    mymodel->setData(idx,QVariant::fromValue(Pets), Qt::UserRole);

    //Now i fill the table with some values...
    QList< QStandardItem * > items;
    items.clear();
    items << new QStandardItem("col0");
    items << new QStandardItem("col1");
    items << new QStandardItem("parrot");
    items << new QStandardItem("col3");
    mymodel->appendRow(items);

    items.clear();
    items << new QStandardItem("col0");
    items << new QStandardItem("col1");
    items << new QStandardItem("cat");
    items << new QStandardItem("col3");
    mymodel->appendRow(items);
    }
```

Then I should be able to recover the `ComboBox` contents from the delegate class:

```
void ComboBoxDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor,
                                     const QModelIndex &index) const
   {
   QString value = index.model()->data(index, Qt::EditRole).toString();
   QComboBox *cBox = static_cast<QComboBox*>(editor);

   if(index.column()==2) {
      QModelIndex idx = index.model()->index(0, 2, QModelIndex());
      cBox->addItem( index.model()->data(idx,Qt::UserRole).toStringList().at(0) );
      cBox->addItem( index.model()->data(idx,Qt::UserRole).toStringList().at(1) );
      cBox->addItem( index.model()->data(idx,Qt::UserRole).toStringList().at(2) );
      }
   cBox->setCurrentIndex(cBox->findText(value));
   }
```

The project compiles well but when I click on a cell to change the `QComboBox` value the program **crashes** and I got an "Invalid parameter passed to C run time function."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was that I was trying to use mymodel->setdata() before I append rows to the model.

So If at first I should do:

```
QList< QStandardItem * > items;
items.clear();
items << new QStandardItem("col0");
items << new QStandardItem("col1");
items << new QStandardItem("parrot");
items << new QStandardItem("col3");
mymodel->appendRow(items);
```

and ONLY then...

```
QModelIndex idx = mymodel->index(0, 2, QModelIndex());
mymodel->setData(idx,QVariant::fromValue(Pets), Qt::UserRole);
```

This solved the issue.

Thank you all.